# Making squid use a proxy

Tags: iptables, proxy, squid, socks

I have a home network with 4-5 clients, and a server. The server runs Squid 2.7. The clients are all configured to use squid as a proxy server. I would like to be able to establish an SSH tunnel with dynamic port forwarding (basically set up a SOCKS proxy), and make all of squid's traffic be tunneled through the SSH connection (or SOCKS proxy) to the remote machine.

I don't think there is an option within squid's config files to do this, so I think that I might have to use iptables - but I am unsure of how to construct such a rule.

If this is not possible, then I might be able to install squid on the remote server, and then use cache_peer. However, I would like to avoid that if at all possible. The fewer the services the better (in my book) - and performance isn't my HIGHEST priority here. I would also like to avoid upgrading to Squid 3.0 at this point... although if it is the best option, I will consider it.

Comment: What is "the remote machine" you are talking about?

Comment: It's the machine running sshd which my proxy server would connect to, and tunnel traffic through.

Comment: Ok, but what kind of traffic? Traffic directed to that machine? Traffic meant for other machines behind it? Generic Internet traffic?

Comment: Traffic meant for both the machines behind the proxy, and for the machine it's self. Although the machines behind the proxy are the most important.

Comment: So basically you want a VPN...

Comment: I could do it with a VPN, yes. I was originally hoping to do it with an SSH tunnel, but using OpenVPN might be easier (and could come in handy for other things, too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using OpenVPN. I've got another question about that.... but if I end up asking it, I will post separately.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. It wouldn't let me do it to begin with (1 day self answer rule)